# capistrano sub-modules git-ssh.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

A new error has starting borking our deployment script with capistrano and I am at a loss as to what went wrong.  We recently switched to using a submodule but no matter what I try the deploy keeps choking with this message for 2 of our APIs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
DEBUG [b65195b3] Running [ ! -d /opt/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247 ] on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [b65195b3] Command: [ ! -d /opt/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247 ]
DEBUG [b65195b3] Finished in 1.014 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 INFO [c62b9ae7] Running mkdir -p /tmp/digest/digest/ on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [c62b9ae7] Command: mkdir -p /tmp/digest/digest/
 INFO [c62b9ae7] Finished in 0.866 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [30b87a02] Running chmod +x /tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [30b87a02] Command: chmod +x /tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh
 INFO [30b87a02] Finished in 0.116 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [7e5c34f1] Running git ls-remote git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiDigest.git on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [7e5c34f1] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh git ls-remote git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiDigest.git )
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
DEBUG [7e5c34f1]    a7f25a5de1a108403eab4b31bd1561c384759852    HEAD
DEBUG [7e5c34f1]    a7f25a5de1a108403eab4b31bd1561c384759852    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [7e5c34f1]    49374f21b1b53662b17de471924d7cab5bfac088    refs/heads/staging
DEBUG [7e5c34f1] Finished in 2.326 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [e4be4222] Running mkdir -pv /home/apps/digest/shared /home/apps/digest/releases on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [e4be4222] Command: mkdir -pv /home/apps/digest/shared /home/apps/digest/releases
 INFO [e4be4222] Finished in 0.905 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [a618ff97] Running [ -f /home/apps/digest/repo/HEAD ] on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [a618ff97] Command: [ -f /home/apps/digest/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [a618ff97] Finished in 0.916 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO The repository mirror is at /home/apps/digest/repo
DEBUG [6c948acf] Running if test ! -d /home/apps/digest/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/digest/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [6c948acf] Command: if test ! -d /home/apps/digest/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/digest/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
DEBUG [6c948acf] Finished in 0.863 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [2d21a5e9] Running git remote update on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [2d21a5e9] Command: cd /home/apps/digest/repo && git remote update
DEBUG [2d21a5e9]    Fetching origin
DEBUG [2d21a5e9]    Fetching origin
DEBUG [2d21a5e9]    From github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiDigest
DEBUG [2d21a5e9]       9695797..a7f25a5  master     -> master
 INFO [2d21a5e9] Finished in 1.443 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [68db389a] Running if test ! -d /home/apps/digest/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/digest/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [68db389a] Command: if test ! -d /home/apps/digest/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/digest/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [68db389a] Finished in 0.881 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [c9703c18] Running git clone -b master --single-branch --recursive . /home/apps/digest/releases/20131118222409 on 208.94.36.62
DEBUG [c9703c18] Command: cd /home/apps/digest/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/digest/git-ssh.sh git clone -b master --single-branch --recursive . /home/apps/digest/releases/20131118222409 )
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Cloning into '/home/apps/digest/releases/20131118222409'...
DEBUG [c9703c18]    done.
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Submodule 'lib/api_client' (git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git) registered for path 'lib/api_client'
DEBUG [c9703c18]    done.
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Submodule 'lib/api_client' (git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git) registered for path 'lib/api_client'
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Cloning into 'lib/api_client'...
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Submodule 'lib/api_client' (git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git) registered for path 'lib/api_client'
DEBUG [c9703c18]    error:
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Submodule 'lib/api_client' (git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git) registered for path 'lib/api_client'
DEBUG [c9703c18]    cannot run /tmp/digest/git-ssh.sh: No such file or directory
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Submodule 'lib/api_client' (git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git) registered for path 'lib/api_client'
DEBUG [c9703c18]
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Submodule 'lib/api_client' (git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git) registered for path 'lib/api_client'
DEBUG [c9703c18]    fatal: unable to fork
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Submodule 'lib/api_client' (git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git) registered for path 'lib/api_client'
DEBUG [c9703c18]    Clone of 'git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiClient.git' into submodule path 'lib/api_client' failed
cap aborted!
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Nothing written
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:125:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:149:in `block in _execute'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-scm-gitsubmodules-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/gitsubmodules.cap:19:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-scm-gitsubmodules-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/gitsubmodules.cap:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:89:in `with'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-scm-gitsubmodules-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/gitsubmodules.cap:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/Users/chrishough/Placewise/code/ApiDigest/.bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => gitsubmodules:create_release
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the issue:

```
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
```

... note the duplicate `digest` in the path. This is called successfully in the first round of checkouts:

```
DEBUG [7e5c34f1] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh git ls-remote git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/ApiDigest.git )
```

... but fails a little further down the stack:

```
DEBUG [c9703c18] Command: cd /home/apps/digest/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/digest/git-ssh.sh git clone -b master --single-branch --recursive . /home/apps/digest/releases/20131118222409 )
```

The `GIT_SSH` environment variable is set to `/tmp/digest/git-ssh.sh`

```
DEBUG [c9703c18]    cannot run /tmp/digest/git-ssh.sh: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure where in your configuration this needs to be fixed, but I hope this sets you on the right path!

Comment: Thank you so much @peat this helped me find the problem! Doh! I had to update a tmp path on my deploy.rb.  Seems odd, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this path right?

```
GIT_SSH=/tmp/digest/digest/git-ssh.sh
```

digest twice?